# How to mask the mini-scroller bar on the left of a popover?

Tags: ionic4, popover

On Ionic 4 i have a popover window, that i open from a button on the toolbar (standard code).
A small mini-scroll bar is present on the right of the popover, over the content of the item-list.

How can i mask it without any side effects?

**popover.component.ts:**

```js
<ion-content>
  <ion-list class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Annuler et Fermer</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="checkmark-circle" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Fermer et Sauver</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**popover.component.scss:**

```js
ion-list {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  ion-item {
    ion-label {
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
  }
}
```

I have already try to add a class to the content div of the popover to set overflow: hidden or auto, but that doesn't work well: The scroll bar disappear but the content of the popover can scroll to a long blank zone.

**popover.component.ts: (with no-scroll class)**

```js
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
  <ion-list class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Annuler et Fermer</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="checkmark-circle" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Fermer et Sauver</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**popover.component.scss:**

```js
ion-list {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  ion-item {
    ion-label {
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
  }
}
.no-scroll {
  --overflow: hidden; // <-- mask the scroll-bar but show a wide blank zone under the ion-list
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading on the web and more by testing every properties in chrome dev tools,
i have found a clean solution:

**popover.component.ts:**

```js
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
  <ion-list class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
    <ion-item color="" class="">
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Annuler et Fermer</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item color="" class="">
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="checkmark-circle" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Fermer et Sauver</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**popover.component.scss:**

```js
ion-list {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  ion-item {
    ion-label {
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
  }
}
.no-scroll {
  --overflow: hidden;  // <-- this mask the scroll-bar but add a side effect

  // Solution is to add: overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;  // <-- this mask the wide blank zone added under the content
}
```

If someone can also comment or reply to give me explanations about this behaviour?

Or give a better/cleaner solution ?

thanks.